# How can I fill the background of each of the label white?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
 \documentclass {standalone}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
              \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,...,6}{
         \draw (0,0) grid (6,6); 
       \node[black, fill=white, below] at (\x,3){\x}; 

 }


    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

The command only works here for the last label which is 6
[image: The command only works here for the last label which is 6]

How do I block the  overlapping lines for each of the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the grid first:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (0,0) grid (6,6); 
  \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,...,6}{
       \node[black, fill=white, below] at (\x,3){\x}; 
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are drawing one node (with white background) then the grid, then other node, the grid again,... This is because you put the grid *inside* the `\foreach`. If you put the grid before the `\foreach` you have it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm] {standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (0,0) grid (6,6); % outside the \foreach, we want to draw just one grid
  \foreach \x in {0,...,6}
    \node[black, fill=white, below] at (\x,3){\x}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]